# how to make listview from JSON -> Sqlite?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview

I am working in an android application in which the data is in the form of json and from json data is saved in Sqlite. Till now i have saved the json to sqlite but when i am trying to get data in listview , the application crashes

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private EditText editTextName;
SharedPreferences sp;
private String jsonResult;
private ListView listView;
private Button b;
EditText etname, et;
TextView tv;
String myJSON;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "notice";
private CategoryHelper databaseHelper;
Button get, store, select;

JSONArray peoples = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

ListView list;


public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.noticelist);
    //select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    databaseHelper=new CategoryHelper(MainActivity.this);
    databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();


    //SharedPreferences myprefs= getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    // String session_id= myprefs.getString("session_id", null);


    //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fname);

    //textView.setText("Welcome "+session_id);


/*select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        select_seqlite();
    }
});*/



    // load icons from
    // strings.xml


    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    getData();




}
```

//send messages stop

```
//get json data start
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONArray peoples = new JSONArray(myJSON);
        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String name=null, date=null;




            if(c.has("notice"))


                name = c.getString("notice");

            databaseHelper.saveCategoryRecord(name);
            Cursor c1 = databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();
            if( c1 != null && c1.moveToFirst()) {
                date = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));

            }
            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,date);
            Log.i("tagconvertstr", "[" + date + "]");
            personList.add(persons);

        }




           /*ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                   Messages.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                   new String[]{TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                   new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.address}
           );*/


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item1,
                new String[]{TAG_NAME},
                new int[]{R.id.name}


        );
```

// http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html // Custom Adapter for List View

```
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
   /* list.setAdapter(adapter);*/
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+myJSON+"]");

    }
}

private void select_seqlite() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();

    Cursor c = databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            DisplayContact(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }


}

private void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"name " + c.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            SharedPreferences myprefs= getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            String session_id= myprefs.getString("session_id", null);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {

                String postReceiverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/progress_card/teacher/teacher_notice.php";

                // HttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

                // add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "suyash1"));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = resEntity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+result+"]");
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}
```

//get json data stop
}

CatergoryHelper (Sqlite)

```
public class CategoryHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "category.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbcategory";

    public static final String CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    Category openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public CategoryHelper(Context context){
        openHelper = new Category(context);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void saveCategoryRecord(String name) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
    public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
        return database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }
    private class Category extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public Category(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                    +  CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT )" );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
}
```

Logcat

```
01-16 15:04:21.735  29380-29380/org.pitechnologies.jsontosqlite E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.pitechnologies.jsontosqlite, PID: 29380
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at org.pitechnologies.jsontosqlite.MainActivity.showList(MainActivity.java:131)
        at org.pitechnologies.jsontosqlite.MainActivity$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:249)
        at org.pitechnologies.jsontosqlite.MainActivity$1GetDataJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:196)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: I solved the Null Pointer Exception problem but now i am getting another one, I have updated my logcat

Answer (score 0):

Regards to this error:

```
Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Check the Cursor in this line,

```
Cursor c1 = databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();

                HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();
                persons.put(TAG_NAME,c1.getString(0));
                personList.add(persons);
```

---

you should move to next before you call

```
c1.getString(0)
```

Comment: Thanks its working now , but data is repeating in listview.

Comment: can you update your new code, usually that may happen because you add the same item, which means you don't declare new object for each list view item.

Answer (score 0):

move this method call from onCreate to getData()'s onPostExecute(). and one more suggestion please remove this meaning less lines you are using two places.

```
 databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();
```

remove from

```
      onCreate()
    //showList();
```

and put it on

```
         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
```

and try to close the db after use otherwise db give you a database leak problem. like creating two methods.

```
       void open() {
         database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       }

       void close() {
          database.close();
       }
```

and call this method like this

```
        public void saveCategoryRecord(String name) {
             ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
             contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_NAME, name);
             open();
             database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
             close();
         }

         public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
             open();
             Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
             close();
             return c;
            }
```

and remove this line from constructor.

```
 database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Hope this will works for you.